# Ошибка в коде silero.py, синтез речи?

Tags: python, синтезатор-речи, голосовой-поиск

Решил потестить библиотеку silero, запускаю код, ошибка происходит в файле silero.py, то есть в файле самой библиотеки
Вот текст ошибки:

```
Возникло исключение: RuntimeError
open file failed because of errno 2 on fopen: No such file or directory, 
file path: C:\Users\Стас/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero- 
models_master\src\silero\model\ru_v3.pt
File "C:\Users\Стас\.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero- 
models_master\src\silero\silero.py", line 87, in silero_tts
imp = package.PackageImporter(model_path)
File "C:\Users\Стас\Documents\Assistent\test.py", line 14, in <module>
model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
```

Сам файл при этом присутствует в это директории

Вот код:

```
import torch
import sounddevice as sd
import time

language = 'ru'
model_id = 'ru_v3'
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'aidar'
put_accent = True
put_yo = True
device = torch.device('cpu')
text = 'Привет хабр'

model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                          model='silero_tts',
                          language=language,
                      speaker=model_id)
model.to(device)

audio = model.apply_tts(text=text,
                        speaker=speaker,
                        sample_rate=sample_rate,
                        put_accent=put_accent,
                        put_yo=put_yo)
print(text)

sd.play(audio, sample_rate)
time.sleep(len(audio) / sample_rate)
sd.stop()
```

Comment: А у тебя это есть ? 'snakers4/silero-models'

Comment: На основе чего код? Там наверное и указано где взять 'snakers4/silero-models'

Comment: Да есть, проверял, он устанавливается при установке silero

Comment: No such file or directory ошибка говорит об обратном.

Comment: Так поэтому я сюда и написал

Comment: У вас в папке со скриптом есть такая папка snakers4 а в ней такая silero-models?

Comment: В папке со скриптом нет, но и скрипт у меня вообще на другом диске. То есть сам файл silero.py от библиотеки silero ссылается по этому пути, и он у всех одинаковый, за исключением имени пользователя конечно, я смотрел, проверял

Comment: А так весь путь проверял, да все названия правильные в правильном порядке и существуют

Comment: snakers4_silero- models_master в данном случае - это единая папка

Comment: Где вы нашли такую конструкцию repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',?

Comment: Скорее всего антивирус не даёт получить файл. Попробуйте запустить скрипт на выполнение от имени Администратора.

Comment: Конструкция из офф статьи на гитхабе

Comment: Я ваш скрипт запустил у меня работает.

Comment: Скачаивает файлы из интернета и всё. Я вам дал наводку по поводу блокировки Антивирусом, почему вы молчите, да нет проверили не проверили? Вам это надо вообще или нет?

Comment: Спасибо, решил)

Comment: И в чём проблема была?

Comment: В следущий раз не обижайтесь если на вас ни кто не захочет тратить своё время)

Comment: Не обижаюсь, можно понять) Никто мне ничего не обязан) Проблема была в русском имени пользователя в папке Users

Comment: @zeellss извините, а как вы смогли это исправить? переименовали папку пользователя или изменили директорию загрузки моделей?

Comment: @QuL1ux Да, но ни к чему хорошему это не привело, много проблем со системой и т д. Не советую, лучше переустановить винду просто

Comment: @zeellss В документации был второй пример кода, который скачивал модели в директорию с программой, я им воспользовался