# Код python silero не воспроизводит звук

Tags: python

Программа должна озвучивать текст при помощи модуля Silero, но выводит ошибку.

```
import torch
import sounddevice as sd
import time

language = 'ru'
model_id = 'v4_ru'
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'baya'
put_accent = True
put_yo = True
device = torch.device('cpu')

text = 'Привет мир'

model, example_text = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                                     model='silero_tts',
                                     language=language,
                                     speaker=model_id)

model.to(device)

audio = model.apply_tts(text=example_text,
                        speaker=speaker,
                        sample_rate=sample_rate,
                        put_accent = put_accent,
                        put_yo = put_yo)

model.to(device)



print(text)

sd.play(audio, sample_rate)
time.sleep(len(audio) / sample_rate)
sd.stop()
```

ошибки в консоли:

Using cache found in C:\Users\Никита/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\tinker3\main.py", line 16, in 
model, example_text = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File"C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 566, in load
model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File"C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 595, in _load_local
model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Никита/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master\src\silero\silero.py", line 87, in silero_tts
imp = package.PackageImporter(model_path)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File"C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\torch\package\package_importer.py", line 95, in **init**
self.zip_reader = torch._C.PyTorchFileReader(self.filename)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: open file failed because of errno 2 on fopen: No such file or directory, file path: C:\Users\Никита/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master\src\silero\model\v4_ru.pt

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
model_id = 'v4_ru'
```

примените

```
model_id = 'ru_v4'
```

или

```
model_id = 'ru_v3'
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
File"C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Packages\..."
              ^^^^^^
```

Рекомендую установить и библиотеку и вообще Питон в другое место на диске, так чтобы в пути не было русских названий папок. Это известная проблема Питона и для данной библиотеки она тоже подтверждается судя по этим вопросам по `Silero`, где наблюдается аналогичная ошибка и в комментариях к первому вопросу есть именно такое решение от автора вопроса:

[Ошибка в коде silero.py, синтез речи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1434356/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-silero-py-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8)

[Ошибка в коде, как я понял, не открывается нужный файл: RuntimeError: open file failed because of errno 2 on fopen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485886/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-runtimeerror-open-file)